# systemd-journal in Debian Jessie LXC container eats 100% CPU

Tags: debian, lxc, systemd

After creating fresh LXC based on Debian Jessie, on a Ubuntu 14.04, systemd-journal eats all CPU available.

```
lxc-create -n jessie -t debian
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC#Incompatibility_with_systemd):

Add to container's config `/var/lib/lxc/{container}/config`:

```
lxc.autodev = 1
lxc.kmsg = 0
```

and comment out `/var/lib/lxc/{container}/rootfs/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`

```
  ConditionPathExists=/dev/tty0
```

Then restart container. Same problem with Fedora host mentioned [here](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-users/2014-October/007907.html)

Comment: per the above mentioned Fedora post,  you also need to:

    Delete ${LXC_PATH}/${container}/rootfs.dev/kmsg

Comment: Now that the kmsg parameter is no longer supported in lxc, is there a way to solve this issue without it @Tombart?